# Integrate Dolby Vision 8.4 Metadata into streams encoded by x265

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, hdr, libx265, dolby

I have the original video captured by iPhone 13 Pro, with Dolby Vision profile 8.4, HLG. Is there a way I can compress it with x265, so that I can get almost the same quality in a far smaller size.

An image from Dolby Vision official website: [Dolby Vision Encoding of mezzanine assets](https://professionalsupport.dolby.com/s/article/Dolby-Vision-Encoding-of-mezzanine-assets)
[image: 2]
What's a "VES muxer" we can use to combine x265-encoded stream and RPU stream from the original file taken by iPhone.

Comment: Why do you think that HW x265 encoders in iPhone are worse than x265? They probably are... But... The fact of the matter even ffmleg cannot decode open gop of that hevc quite accurately yet.

Comment: On an iPhone, a 4K60fps HEVC stream need to be at least 48 MBps not to show too many macro blocks and compression effect, on libx265, 10 MBps is enough, 20 MBps can give visually lossless output, there will be little quality loss and the file size will decrease to 1/2-1/4 of the original.

Comment: But libx265 also supports speed presets, try placebo, it will be too slow for anything real time. So you are comparing apples and oranges. Are you sure Apple does not use libx265, BTW, on ultrafast?